# Pandas Dataframes remove duplicate index, keep largest value first depending on column value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, time-series, trading

This my current df. I would like to transform the dataframe in 3 steps. I need to remove duplicate time stamps but would like to keep the largest values or smallest values depending on the "Side" column. Please help :)

I have tried `df= df[~df.index.duplicated(keep='first')]` however this doesn't have the option to keep max or min values

The type of the index is datetime format, Price is float and Side is integer, the data frame has 8000+ rows.

```
                          Price      Side  
2021-12-13 00:00:03.285   51700      4     
2021-12-13 00:00:03.315   51675      3    
2021-12-13 00:00:03.333   50123      4    
2021-12-13 00:00:03.333   50200      3    
2021-12-13 00:00:03.333   50225      3   
2021-12-13 00:00:03.333   50250      3    
2021-12-13 00:00:03.421   50123      4     
2021-12-13 00:00:03.421   50117      4     
2021-12-13 00:00:03.421   50110      4    
2021-12-13 00:00:03.671   50100      3
```

1. If the time is duplicated, keep the highest value if the side is "3", if the time is duplicated and the side is "4" keep lowest value.

```
Desired Output:
                          Price      Side  
2021-12-13 00:00:03.285   51700      4     
2021-12-13 00:00:03.315   51675      3    
2021-12-13 00:00:03.333   50123      4 
2021-12-13 00:00:03.333   50250      3     
2021-12-13 00:00:03.421   50110      4     
2021-12-13 00:00:03.671   50100      3
```

2. Create new columns "3" and "4" with the corresponding prices

```
Desired Output:
                          Price      3         4  
2021-12-13 00:00:03.285   51700      0         51700
2021-12-13 00:00:03.315   51675      51675     0  
2021-12-13 00:00:03.333   50123      0         50123
2021-12-13 00:00:03.333   50250      50250     0     
2021-12-13 00:00:03.421   50110      0         50110  
2021-12-13 00:00:03.671   50100      50100     0
```

3. Fill in the blanks with previous values from the same column

```
Desired Output:
                          Price      3         4  
2021-12-13 00:00:03.285   51700      0         51700  
2021-12-13 00:00:03.315   51675      51675     51700  
2021-12-13 00:00:03.333   50123      51675     50123
2021-12-13 00:00:03.333   50250      50250     50123     
2021-12-13 00:00:03.421   50110      50250     50110  
2021-12-13 00:00:03.671   50100      50100     50110
```

Comment: What do you mean by "if side is 3"? Group `2021-12-13 00:00:03.333` has four items, where three sides are 3 and one is 4. How do you determine the side for that time?

Comment: Oh wait, you want to group by `time` _and_ `side`

Answer (score 2):

```
new_df = (df
    .groupby([pd.Grouper(level=0), 'Side'])
    .apply(lambda x: x['Price'].max() if x['Side'].mode()[0] == 3 else x['Price'].min())
    .reset_index()
)
new_df = (
    pd.concat([
        new_df,
        (new_df
            .pivot(columns='Side', values=0)
            .ffill()
            .fillna(0)
        )
    ], axis=1)
    .drop('Side', axis=1)
    .rename({0: 'Price'}, axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                    index  Price        3        4
0 2021-12-13 00:00:03.285  51700      0.0  51700.0
1 2021-12-13 00:00:03.315  51675  51675.0  51700.0
2 2021-12-13 00:00:03.333  50250  50250.0  51700.0
3 2021-12-13 00:00:03.333  50123  50250.0  50123.0
4 2021-12-13 00:00:03.421  50110  50250.0  50110.0
5 2021-12-13 00:00:03.671  50100  50100.0  50110.0
```

Compact version:

```
new_df = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(level=0), 'Side']).apply(lambda x: x['Price'].max() if x['Side'].mode()[0] == 3 else x['Price'].min()).reset_index()
new_df = pd.concat([new_df, new_df.pivot(columns='Side', values=0).ffill().fillna(0)], axis=1).drop('Side', axis=1).rename({0:'Price'}, axis=1))
```

Comment: you don't need to reset_index, you can do `groupby(level = 0, 'Side')`

Comment: @sammywemmy I tried that before, but it didn't work. It just ignore the `by='Side'` and grouped only by `level=0`.

Comment: my bad : ``df.groupby([pd.Grouper(level=0), 'Side'])``

Comment: Sweet! Although, it's actually only 2 chars shorter... :P

Comment: lol, I mention it, cos it might be more efficient to avoid the index reset, since a groupby generates an index. If you already have an index, it should be computationally more efficient ... but you never know ...

Comment: I always forget about that. So the character reduction is really useless. Even a very minor speed improvement would be worth 10 or 20 more characters really.

Answer (score 0):

This is one option, which is a bit long:

```py
(df.assign(temp = df.Side.map({4:'low', 3:'high'}))
.groupby([pd.Grouper(level=0), 'Side', 'temp'], sort = False)
.Price
.agg(['min', 'max'])
.unstack('Side')
.loc(axis=1)[[('max', 3), ('min', 4)]]
.droplevel(level = 0,axis = 1)
.droplevel(level = 'temp')
.assign(Price=lambda df: df[3].where(df[3].notna(), df[4]))
.ffill()
.fillna(0)
.astype(int)
.rename_axis(columns = None)
)

                             3      4  Price
2021-12-13 00:00:03.285      0  51700  51700
2021-12-13 00:00:03.315  51675  51700  51675
2021-12-13 00:00:03.333  51675  50123  50123
2021-12-13 00:00:03.333  50250  50123  50250
2021-12-13 00:00:03.421  50250  50110  50110
2021-12-13 00:00:03.671  50100  50110  50100
```

This assumes that the only values in `Side` are 3 and 4.